# Embedded Jetty Server giving Same response for different urls , without restarting its not working,

Tags: rest, jersey, jetty, jersey-2.0, embedded-jetty

I have developed the embedded jetty server to implement the rest service.
I have setup the eclipse project in the eclipse. 
I have written the sample program which returns some details through rest url,

I was successfully compiled the program and created a Runnable jar.
I was successfully able to run the Jar files and the server started and running on the port which i gave ,

I have the testing url
 http://localhost:1234/getuser/1

```
it gave me the user details in the response
 <username>test1</username>
```

I ran the same url with different id no 
  http://localhost:1234/getuser/2

```
 Again it gave me the same result,
   `<username>test1</username>`

 So i have restarted the server and then it got me the proper details,
       <username>test2</username>

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           ServletContextHandler context = new 
      ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
      context.setContextPath("/");

      Server jettyServer = new Server(1234);
      jettyServer.setHandler(context);

      ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
      jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);



      jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames", org.test.test.getuser.class.getCanonicalName());




      try {
       jettyServer.start();
       jettyServer.join();

      } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } finally{
       jettyServer.destroy();
      }
     }
```

Without restarting the jetty web server how to get the proper results.
Is there any thing i need to add in the code to get it worked.
or any settings i need to do for this auto refresh?

Comment: I have found the answer and closing it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, jetty server was able to refresh automatically, there was a object refresh didnt happened in the back end, resolved it from myside and it worked